# Error with helm-swoop

Tags: helm, search

`helm-swoop` no longer works for me. Whenever I try to use it, i get the message

> Symbol's value as variable is void: helm-swoop-pattern

I am using the latest package from MELPA (20170923.2127) which has not been updated since September. So I have no idea what has caused this issue to suddenly crop up.

I am using Emacs 25.3 on macOS. I do not have any `helm-swoop` specific config in my init.el and am using it "plain-vanilla".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed and merged. https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop/pull/125

I just updated helm-swoop to version 20180215.354 from MELPA. This version contains the fix and the problem is indeed gone.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue caused by a breaking change in Helm: https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop/issues/123.

Feel free to manually apply a fix from https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop/pull/124.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the maintainer of `helm-swoop` seems to have abandoned the package, I switched to [`swiper-helm`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper-helm). It also offers multi-buffer search based on helm and it's better maintained.